# Comparing double decimal number

Tags: php, decimal

I want to compare version numbers of apps/software which sometimes may have two decimal points such as:

```
1.0
1.1
1.0.01
1.0.1
2.0
2.5
3.0
```

etc. etc..

What would be the correct way of comparing these numbers?

I tried a this but get an error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DNUMBER in /home/videocoo/public_html/dev/vc-admin/test_cmp.php  on line 2

```
$a = 1.2.11;
$b = 1.2.0;

if($a > $b){
    print"<br />a is greater";
} else {
    print"<br />b is greater";
}
```

Is it incorrect to make the numbers into a string, wrapping them in double quotes? It seemed to give the right comparison every time I tested different numbers. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `version_compare()` [PHP Reference](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php)

```
<?php
$versionA = '1.0.1';
$versionB = '1.0.2';

if (version_compare($versionA, $versionB) >= 0) {
    echo 'Version B is equal to or greater than Version A';
}

if (version_compare($versionA, $versionB, '<')) {
    echo 'Version A is less than Version B';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Comparing the version numbers as strings won't work: check `1.9` vs. `1.11`.  You can use `version_compare` instead: http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php.